# Problemas con posicion CSS

Tags: css

Tengo un nav a la izquierda y necesito que cada vez que pase el mouse por cada elemento li se despliegue la descripcion. ya esta parte la logre pero el área que se despliega no se sobrepone al padre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que se muestre de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestro la forma en que lo estoy haciendo

```css
.sidebar {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: fixed;
            margin-top: 64px;
            width: 64px;
            height: calc(100% - 64px);
            float: left;
            background: #16181E;
            z-index: 5;
        }

        .sidebar > ul > li{
            position: relative;
            color: #000;         
            margin-top: 20px;
            font-size: 24px;
            width: 64px;
            height: 64px;
            background: #16181E;
            transition:all 0.3s ease-in;
        }

        .sidebar > ul > li:hover{
            width: 200px;
            height: 64px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            background-color: #f3faff;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f3faff 0%, #fffbfb 100%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f3faff 0%,#fffbfb 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f3faff 0%,#fffbfb 100%);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f3faff', endColorstr='#fffbfb',GradientType=0 );
            box-shadow: 0 8px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No se puede asegurar completamente porque falta el html completo, pero tienes un `overflow:hidden`en el `.sidebar`, con lo que estas impidiendo que se vea nada que sobresalga de sus limites

Comment: Gracias, justamente esa eso.